# python fool-proof grade measuring

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def func(grades):
    first,*middle,last=grades
    try:
        avg=sum(middle)/len(middle)
        print(avg)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Atleast 3 grades must be inputed")
    except NameError:
        print("no letters are allowed in Grades")

func([50,60,60,60,70,90])
func([20,a,4,40])
```

hello i am using this function to calculate the average of the grades in the middle(excluding first and last grade).

My question is how can i improve this function to make it "fool proof" i.e (no matter what was the input the code keeps running without crashing).

I tried using `except:`
 to overcome it but still `NameError`.
*it was stated in the answers that error is caused outside the function,can this error be solved?

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Currently it's not clear what you are asking

Comment: What do you expect the output with `sum`?

Comment: overcome any error and print something out for the user no matter what they input,instead of letting program crash

Comment: `a` is the name of a variable that you did not declare. Hence NameError. You probably ment `'a'` - which is a string.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Exactly my thoughts.

Comment: @BlackThunder sum of items in the middle only(ignore first and last)

Comment: @PatrickArtner i will not be using the program someone else will,i do not want the program to crash even if they input wrong data

Comment: What is the purpose of doing `first,*middle,last=grades` here?

Comment: @zvone *middle allows me to average the middle items only(ignoring first and last element)

Comment: @zvone this works no matter the list length

Comment: @timmy But you are not sorting the list, so the first and last element could be anything, so your function would say that the average of `[75, 4, 91]` is `4`? That seems wrong.

Comment: -5 because no one was able  to give me the answer i needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NameError` is nothing to do with the function, it is because you are trying to use a variable, `a`, when initialising a list which you haven't defined.

It looks like you meant to test with a string instead:

```
func([20, 'a', 4, 40])
```

---

But nevertheless, your `try..except` still wont catch the `TypeError` thrown when trying to sum a list which rather than the `NameError`: contains a string, you should catch this for the wrong type. You should also catch `ValueError` in case less than two grades were entered:

```
def func(grades):
    try:
        first,*middle,last=grades
        avg=sum(middle)/len(middle)
        print(avg)
    except (ZeroDivisionError, ValueError):
        print("At least 3 grades must be inputed")
    except TypeError:
        print("no letters are allowed in Grades")
```

which warns the user if the wrong data type is passed:

```
>>> func([20, 'a', 4, 40])
no letters are allowed in Grades
```

Comment: this will only fix if they enter
func([20,'a',40,60])

Comment: @timmy See the updated answer, this now catches if they enter less than three grades (with the `ZeroDivisionError` catching if they entered `2` grades and the `ValueError` catching if they entered only `1`) and also the `TypeError` catches if they enter the wrong data type (such as the `'a'` string here).

Comment: ValueError haven't thought of that thanks,i guess i'll have to go in the list and transform any non-integer into string then test for TypeError ,i think this is the only way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`sum` is raising an error if string is in the list. So its ignoring the `try` statement. You need to loop through the list and if string is found raise error.

```
def func(grades):
    try:
        first,*middle,last=grades
        for mid in middle:
            if isinstance(mid,str):raise ValueError
        avg=sum(middle)/len(middle)
        print(avg)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Atleast 3 grades must be inputed")
    except ValueError:
        print("no letters are allowed in Grades")
```

Using:

```
func([50,60,60,60,70,90])
func([20,"a",4,40])
```

Output:

```
62.5
no letters are allowed in Grades
```

If you want to ignore errors in the code:

```
try:
    func([50,60,60,60,70,90])
    func([20,a,4,40])
except:  #ignore every error
    print("Invalid Data!")  #will continue/no crash
```

Output:

```
62.5
Invalid Data!
```

Comment: this will only fix if they enter func([20,'a',40,60])
not func([30,a,50,60])

Comment: @BlackThunder i want to display warnings if they input wrongly,this is only the beginning of code,i want the rest of the program to continue and not crash

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comment: you are feeding `a` ( a variable ) to your function, without declaring it - hence `NameError`. This occures *before* you are inside your function. You *can not* handle it inside of it - you would have to handle it around the function call:

```
try:
    calcfunc([20,a,4,40])  # a is the name of a variable that python does not know about
except NameError:
    print("Dont call stuff with variables that you did not declare!")
```

---

Lets improve upon your code by using custom Errors in the vain attempt to make it foolproof:

```
class InputTooShortError(ValueError):
    pass

class NotAnIntError(ValueError):
    pass

def calcfunc(grades):
    try:
        if len(grades) < 3:
            raise InputTooShortError()

        first,*middle,last=grades

        if not all(isinstance(p,int) for p in middle):
            raise NotAnIntError() 

        avg=sum(middle)/len(middle)
        print("Avg of {} = {}".format(middle,avg))
    except InputTooShortError:
        print("Atleast 3 grades must be inputed")
    except NotAnIntError:
        print("Your input contains non-numbers: {}".format(grades))
        correct = [first]+[p for p in middle if isinstance(p,int)]+[last]
        print("Using only {} as input:".format(correct))
        calcfunc(correct)

calcfunc([])
calcfunc([20,'a',4,40])       
calcfunc([50,60,60,60,70,90])

try:
    calcfunc([20,a,4,40]) 
except NameError:
    print("Dont call stuff with variables that you did not declare!")
```

Output:

```
# calcfunc([])
Atleast 3 grades must be inputed

# calcfunc([20,'a',4,40])
Your input contains non-numbers: [20, 'a', 4, 40]
Using only [20, 4, 40] as input:
Avg of [4] = 4.0

# calcfunc([50,60,60,60,70,90])
Avg of [60, 60, 60, 70] = 62.5

# calcfunc([20,a,4,40]) 
Dont call stuff with variables that you did not declare!
```

This will still crash if you feed it a non-list as input. You can solve this by using

```
if not isInstance(grades,list):
    # create another error and handle it
```

You can allow all kinds of iterables if you use

```
from collections import Iterable

if not isinstance(e, Iterable):
    # do something
```

Comment: it will also crash if i input calcfunc([20,a,4,40])

Comment: @timmy Yep - it will. And thats because it crashes "outside" of the function. If you want to handle it, you need to add a `try: except:` around the call of your function. Python is unable to call into the function because one of the parameters it has to provide to the function is unknown to it. See edit.

Comment: oh i understand so i must make function before the avg function to handle it.